# C++ while loop not functioning as intended

Tags: c++

I'm very new to coding, and have been frustrated in the last few days because of my assignment, where I'm supposed to create a supermarket-like program, the issue I'm having is that I've created a while loop that is supposed to stop when 'f' is entered, prompting it to move on to the next set of code, issue is, that it's not doing that. Can someone please help?? Thanks.

```
#include <stdlib.h> //used to terminate the program
#include <string> //used for the string variable
#include <iomanip> //used for setprecision function
using namespace std;

 string array;
 string Data[3][10]= {{"Milk", "Bread", "Chocolatte","Towel","Toothpaste","Soap","Pen","Biscuits","Lampost","Battery"},
 {"0120001", "0120002", "0120003", "0120004", "0120005", "0120006", "0120007", "0120008", "0120009", "0120010"},
 {"10.50", "5.50", "8.00", "12.10", "6.75", "5.20", "2.00", "4.45", "20.50", "10.00"}}; //2D array to store and fetch the table information

 float sumMoney;
int main ()
{
        string currentPrice;
        char customer = 'y';
        while (customer == 'y')
        { //creates a while loop which resets the program if 'y' is inputted, and terminates otherwise

        cout << "*****************************************************" << endl; //simple welcome greeting
        cout << "*  WELCOME TO HERTS SUPERMARKET CHECKOUT SYSTEM     *" << endl;
        cout << "* Scan the barcode or manually type the barcode ID  *" << endl;
        cout << "*****************************************************" << endl;


        bool found = false;
        string ch = "n"; //char used to create the loop
        cout << "Type a Barcode, or type 'f' to finish: " << endl;
        cout << "\n";

        // loops untill input is "f"
        while(ch!="f")
                {
        // takes input assigns it to ch variable which is being test for termination
        cin >> ch;
        // defines counter variable for loop
        int i = 0;
        //used to test if the barcode was found (changed to true when its found else its false)
        //used as a break case for the loop
        found = false;

        //while the item isn't found and the counter isn't at the end of the array
        /*
        This loops through the array and compares it to the search term
        has 2 break cases
        1: found the search term in the array (found = true)
        2: reach the end of the array (i reaches 9)
        If found then price is assigned and outputted
        If not found error is outputted
        */
        while((found==false) && (i<9))  {
            // if the given barcode is equal to the current
            if(ch==Data[1][i])
                                        {
                // the price corresponding to the current i value is assigned
                currentPrice = Data[2][i];
                // break case for found is triggered (case 1)
                found = true;
                // outputs price not needed but was a debug line
                cout << currentPrice << endl;
                                        }
            // if the counter reaches the end of the array without finding something
               else if(i>=9){
                cout << "Not found. Please input a Barcode: " << endl;
                            }
            // increment i
            i++;
                                        }
                }
                        float thechange();
                        {
                        float cashgiven,changegiven,sumprice;

                        sumprice = sumMoney;
                        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint;
                        cout << "\n";

                        cout <<"The total price is: " << char(156) << sumprice << endl;

                        while (sumprice > 0)
                                {
                                    cout << endl;
                                    cout << "Cash received: " << char(156);
                                    cin >> cashgiven;
                                    sumprice = sumprice - cashgiven;

                                    if (sumprice > 0)
                                            {
                                                cout << "Insufficient Funds, cash needed: " << char(156) << sumprice;
                                            }

                                }
                                    if (sumprice <= 0)
                                    {
                                        changegiven = sumprice * -1;
                                        cout  << "The Change Given: " << char(156) << changegiven;
                                    }

                        }




                                    cout << "Next Customer (Y/N): \n";
                                    cin >> customer;
}

                        return 0;
}
```

Comment: EDIT: Forgot to add <iostream> to this code, but it's there.

Comment: You can *actually* edit Stack Exchange posts and that is *vastly* prefered to simply leaving a comment about an oversight. That said, in the case of a code snippet like this you ought to be pasting it in from your development environment so that you *know* it compiles/fails-to-compile as is and can show the output/error-messages.

Answer (score 0):

You have no test of `ch` after `cin >> ch`. So even if the input is an "f", the code will continue to enter the `while` loop. You need to check if the input succeeded and test if the input is an "f" and then, only then, go on to continue with the code.

Answer (score 0):

*You test ch variable as a condition of the while loop, but you read it in the cycle* and you do the operation on it without another if.

To solve this you can add an **if** in the while loop after the cin operation and if enter in the if block you can call **break or continue**

Comment: Like this?  cin >> ch;
            if(ch=="f")
        {
            break;
        }

Comment: Yes, it could be a solution

Comment: What you insert as input?

Comment: No, i mean the input that you pass to the program

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what do you mean?

Comment: The input that you pass to the program when run